# Exported .java with Eclipse issue(s)

Tags: java, eclipse, export

so after quite some searching I still have an issue with an exported .jar file I exported using Eclipse (it is a game using Slick2D & lwjgl if this makes any difference).

Just as a note, I am brand new to Eclipse and also Java, which may be part of the issue.

I have a game created but whenever I export the file, it does not open at all.  I looked on an older SO post and found an answer telling of how to correctly export it, and I followed it to the word.

When I open the .jar with 7zip it shows only "javagame" (the package), META-INF, org, and the .jars of slick & lwjgl.

I know that this is an issue as there should be a .bin etc but there doesn't seem to be and I can't work out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't have jars inside jars (well you can, obviously, but they won't do you any good).

Comment: What happens when you run `java -jar yourfile.jar` on the command line? Please post the entire output in your question.

Comment: It simply says unable to access jarfile Duncan...

Comment: I did load the native, should I post any images?

Comment: @BrianRoach What do I export a game as then to get it to run? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I don't use eclipse for a myriad of reasons. I really have no idea what you would need to do to fix it. Your project has to be built into its own .jar then when run it looks for those other .jar files on the classpath because they're dependencies. They can't be inside the .jar itself unless you explode them and include the actual classes themselves.

Comment: @BrianRoach Could it be a code issue?  If so should I post a screenshot?

Comment: "*It simply says unable to access jarfile Duncan...*" > Please humour me and post the whole output. Often the output can be useful to others.